# How to show a loader on the home page and other pages with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loader

I am trying to implement a page loader on my website using JavaScript. I want a loader to be displayed on the main page for 3 seconds and then disappear, and on all other pages, I want the loader to be hidden as soon as the page finishes loading. I have tried several approaches, including jQuery and PHP, but none of them seem to be working for me.

```js
if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
  // Display the home preloader
  document.getElementById('home-preloader').style.display = 'block';
  // Hide the home preloader after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('home-preloader').style.display = 'none';
  }, 3000);
} else {
  // Display the page preloader
  document.getElementById('page-preloader').style.display = 'block';
  // Wait for the page to finish loading
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Hide the page preloader
    document.getElementById('page-preloader').style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
.preloader {
  display: flex;
  justify - content: center;
  align - items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z - index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100 %;
  height: 100 %;
  background - color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5 s ease - in -out;
}

.preloader img {
  display: block;
  max - width: 100 %;
  max - height: 100 %;
}

#home-preloader {
  background - color: #ffffff;
}

#page-preloader {
  background - color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-preloader">
    <!-- Preloader for other pages -->

    <img src="gif2" alt="Page Loading...">
</div>

<div id="page-preloader">
    <!-- Preloader for home main page -->

    <img src="gif1" alt="Home Loading...">
</div>
```

I have also tried using jQuery and PHP, but none of them seem to work. Can anyone suggest a solution or an alternative approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: the code as it is above will throw an error in the console, because the element you're trying to get with `document.getElementById()` isn't loaded yet. When/how is the script called/included?

Comment: Hi! I took the freedom to edit converting your code to a snippet (the `<>` button in the editor). I added the divs with id home-preloader and page-preloader to let it run in StackOverflow. It seems to run at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , yourFunc);

const function yourFunc (){
 document.getElementById('home-preloader').style.display = 'block';
 setTimeOut(()=>{
 document.getElementById('home-preloader').style.display = 'none';
 },3000)
};
```

With DOMContentLoaded, you can activate it when your page is refreshed and reset it after 3 seconds.

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-domcontentloaded/